# How to query comparing strings pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just seccessfully did the following query:

```
df2.query('Neighborhood == "Not assigned"')
```

The result was the rows witch the value for the column "Neighborhood" was "Not assigned". (in my case zero)

I'm tryind to do this query now:

```
df2.query('Postal Code == "M5A"')
```

But I'm getting invalid syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding

```
df2.query('`Postal Code` == "M5A"')
```

Comment: Solved! But where is ` on the keyboard

Comment: @bakun left to number 1 ~

Answer (score 6):

Try using backticks:

```
df2.query('`Postal Code` == "M5A"')
```